# Color the previous few candles given an event is met

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to find out how I can change colour to past few candles once an event is met.

E.G. given an EMA cross is shown at time `T`, I would like to change color to its previous n candles [`T-1`, `T-2`, ... `T-n`]

Any help super appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
barcolor(color, offset, editable, show_last, title, display)
```

with offset = -1 or offset = -2
see : https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_barcolor